# Table cells / 2d array sorting algorithm

Tags: php, python, c++, algorithm, sorting

Is there an algorithm that could help sort the left table (which is an abstraction for multidimensional array of scalars or objects) down below so the result would be as in the right one, given that there maybe a limited amount of available depth in the right table (e.g. max of 30 rows)?

[image]

And slightly more complex version of the problem (first key in a cell is having precedence over another):

[image]

**EDIT:** And another level of complexity (merge rows/levels if it's safe to do so to prevent redundancy):

[image]

Comment: Sort each column, then use the same algorithm as a merge sort to determine the output.

Comment: sort each column with respect to index of item like 1 comes at 1st index max value comes at last index. and total complexity would be (No of columns x quickshort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using Column = std::vector<int>;
using Matrix = std::vector<Column>;

Column max_col(const Matrix &m) {
    return *std::max_element(m.begin(), m.end(),
                             [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs)
                             {
                                 return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
                             });
}

bool is_element_in_next_rows(const Matrix &m, int element,Column::size_type row) {
    for (auto& col : m) {
        if (row >= col.size()) continue; // out of range
        if (*std::lower_bound(col.begin()+row+1,col.end(),element) == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int min_element_in_row(const Matrix &m, Column::size_type row) { 
    int min_element = max_col(m)[row];
    for (auto& col : m) {
        if (row >= col.size()) continue; // out of range
        if (col[row] != 0) min_element = std::min(min_element, col[row]);
    }
    return min_element;
}

void print_elements(const Matrix &m) {
    for (auto& i : m) {
        for (auto& j : i) {
            std::cout << j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void organize_elements(Matrix &m) {
    for (auto& col : m) {
        std::sort(col.begin(),col.end());
    }
    auto current_max_col = max_col(m);
    for (Column::size_type row{0}; current_max_col.begin()+row!=current_max_col.end(); ++row) {
        int min_element = min_element_in_row(m,row);
        for(auto& col : m) {
            if (row >= col.size()) continue; // out of range
            int candidate = col[row];
            if (candidate > min_element) {
                if (is_element_in_next_rows(m,candidate,row)) {
                    col.insert(col.begin()+row,0);
                }
            }
        }
        current_max_col = max_col(m);
    }
}

int main() {

    Column c1 = {5,6,8};
    Column c2 = {2,5,3,1,4,6};
    Column c3 = {8,7,2,4,5,3,1};

    Matrix m;
    m.push_back(c1);
    m.push_back(c2);
    m.push_back(c3);

    std::cout << "original: \n";
    print_elements(m);
    organize_elements(m);
    std::cout << "organized: \n";
    print_elements(m);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
original: 
5 6 8 
7 2 5 3 1 4 6 
8 7 2 4 5 3 1 
organized: 
0 0 0 0 5 6 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6  
1 2 3 4 5 7 8
```

including pairs is easy, just change how the compare functions are done for them. I don't know if this is what you meant. It can also be further optimized, this was a quick solution that might serve your needs or inspire you for a better one.

Comment: is there any way to implement this algo without using `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`?

Comment: @camel_case you can use `std::find` instead, but lower_bound and upper_bound will be faster because the vector is sorted. The purpose of the function is to find if the element is in the following rows, if the upper and lower bound are the same, means that the element is not present.

Comment: @camel_case The alternative would be to change that if statement for: `if (std::find(col.begin()+row+1,col.end(),element) != col.end()) return true;`

Comment: @camel_case I've just realized that you can do this `if (*std::lower_bound(col.begin()+row+1,col.end(),element) == element)` too

Comment: am I being correct that `max_col()` returns the length of the highest column?

Comment: I'm transpiling your answer into another language, that's why I got these questions :)

Comment: @camel_case nop, it returns the column, a `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @camel_case I made a few changes to make the code a little bit more readable

Comment: you're mvp sir :D

Comment: why there's `current_max_col = max_col(m);` at the end of foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Are the elements in each column bounded the depth of the column? If so just iterate through each column of your multi dimensional array and place the elements in their corresponding row. It is simple to do this if you allocate more memory or you can do it in place with swaps (still O(n)). You can apply more complicated grouping after the fact.